# Reduce padding between table text

Tags: html, css

I want to remove the padding between the rows and between the two lines of text:

```
 <br />
```

Please see the explanation below:

```
http://79.170.44.112/activate-enterprise.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/meet-the-team-image.jpg
```

My table html can be seen at: http://jsfiddle.net/63nzsht1/

My webpage can be seen at:

```
http://79.170.44.112/activate-enterprise.co.uk/meet-the-team/
```

The text is in a separate row (both lines of text in the same cell).

Many thanks!

P.S. Tried

```
cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
```

But I'm still getting the spacing issue, think it must be being pulled from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things causing a gap between the image and the text:

- Because images are displayed inline, there is a reserved gap beneath inline elements to [make way for letter descenders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5804278/1612146). Display your images as blocks or alter their vertical alignment to lost the gap.
- Your table cells display their content in the middle, vertically, by default. So your text is vertically aligned in the middle, not the top. They also have a default padding, remove this.
- Your table has border spacing by default, which can be removed with `border-spacing`:

```
img { display:block; }
table { border-spacing:0; }
td { vertical-align:top; padding:0; }
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/63nzsht1/4/)

Comment: Glad to have helped (:

Answer (score 0):

Try **cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"** properties at the table!

Answer (score 0):

The `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` attributes are supported in all major browsers.

```
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
  <tr>
    <th>h1</th>
    <th>h2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>m</td>
    <td>m</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
padding: 0;
line-height: 12px;
```

to element td which has text in it (define class for that).

http://jsfiddle.net/63nzsht1/10/

Answer (score 0):

```
table {
    line-height:0.8em;
}
td {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    vertical-align:top;
}
img {
    display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/63nzsht1/9/

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the padding to 0px and set the line height to a specific number:

The distance between lines will change using line height.

```
th, td {
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="/cilla/" style=" line-height: 1;">
<span style=" display: block;  line-height: 1.7;">Managing Director</span>
<span style="display: block;"> Cilla McKay</span>
</a>
```

one of way to solve ur problem